# Issue while setting up the spring boot with gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build

I am trying to setting up a Spring boot gradle project in intelliJ. If I am trying with reload button on the gradle pane, it's giving me error for setting.gradle

[image]

but setting.gradle file is already there is the root directory.

[image]

When I tried `./gradlew clean build` on terminal getting the below error:

[image]

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
}

group 'com'
version '1.0'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('11')
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion('11')
}
```

I tried but couldn't figure out what I am missing. Please suggest.

**Update:** I tried to delete gradle installation from the system and executed one another application which was working fine earlier but not even after downloading the gradle version, getting the same error as mentioned above.

I tried Maven project with spring initializr and it successfully build so It seems to be an issue regarding gradle setup on my machine but not sure what to check.**

Regards

Comment: Is the project setup from spring initializr? If not, I'd recommend starting from there, since everything is already set up.

Comment: @0x150 Project was setup from spring initializr only. I tried another fresh project from spring initializr. Getting same error.

Comment: Spring Boot 3 requires Java 17 as a minimum (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes#java-17-baseline-and-java-19-support). Are you trying to build with Java 11?

Comment: @ScottFrederick yes

Comment: You can't use Java 11 to compile an app using Spring Boot 3. You'll have to use at least Java 17.

Comment: @ScottFrederick Ok, but error doesn't seems to be a compilation error, it looks like issue while resolving the dependency

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's going on in your case with the limited build output above and without seeing the entire project, but Gradle will not be able to resolve the plugin unless Java 17 or later used for the build. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33365 for some details and example output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Sure why error message was not that clear. It was related to certificate issue. I added  some organization specific certificate in java cacerts keystore and it resolved the gradle issue with plugin download.

Thanks to All who tried to help.